# Template not found for: -Dsbt.version 0.13.13 lagom/lagom-scala.g8

Tags: scala, lagom

Good afternoon,

I am trying to follow [this hello world tutorial of lagom](https://www.lagomframework.com/get-started-scala.html), however when running the command:

```
sbt new -Dsbt.version=0.13.13 lagom/lagom-scala.g8
```

I get the following error:

```
Template not found for: -Dsbt.version 0.13.13 lagom/lagom-scala.g8
```

As stated in the setup part of the tutorial I have checked my java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

My javac version:

```
javac 1.8.0_131
```

And my sbt version:

```
[info] 0.13.15
```

I have trying running the command with my sbt version as the parameter:

```
sbt new -Dsbt.version=0.13.13 lagom/lagom-scala.g8
```

But it still throws the no template error, could you please point out what am I doing wrong?

Which comply with the prerequisites for the tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to remove the -Dsbt.version=0.13.13 parameter of the commmand.

Running it as:

```
sbt new lagom/lagom-scala.g8
```

Removes the error and it works correctly.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was not the extra flag. The documentation is correct.

You have to use it before the `new` command

```
sbt -Dsbt.version=0.13.13 new lagom/lagom-scala.g8
```

Comment: In that case the error was in the documentation as I was copying the command from it. I see now that it has been updated.